# Building with VSCode Latex Workshopm recipes on build directory

Tags: bibtex, visual-studio-code

I'm working with VSCode WSL and the Latex Workshop extension. I did need to use the \makeglossaries so I created a settings.json like the following as it was indicated in a question I've found.

```
{
"latex-workshop.latex.recipes": [

    {
        "name": "pdflatex ➞ makeglossaries ➞ bibtex ➞ pdflatex × 2",
        "tools": [
            "pdflatex",
            "makeglossaries",
            "bibtex",
            "pdflatex",
            "pdflatex"
        ]
    }
],
"latex-workshop.latex.tools":[

    {
        "name": "pdflatex",
        "command": "pdflatex",
        "args": [
            "-synctex=1",
            "-interaction=nonstopmode",
            "-file-line-error",
            "%DOC%"
        ],
        "env": {}
    },
    {
        "name": "bibtex",
        "command": "bibtex",
        "args": [
            "%DOCFILE%"
        ],
        "env": {}
    },
    {
        "name": "makeglossaries",
        "command": "makeglossaries",
        "args": [
            "%DOCFILE%"
        ]
    }
]
}
```

This used to work perfectly at first, but I did change some files names and it did stop working. When I run the build through the Ctrl+Alt+B it does build on /build (the output directory specified on the extension settings file) but it doesn't build the glossary.

It builds it when I used the created recipe, but all the files are created on the project root instead of the /build directory. I was trying to add some output directory options but I was only able to break everything. I'm not a programmer so I don't really know how to address this and I four hours in I did gave up searching and trying things.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I did activate the full cleaning and added the missing extensions to the list of files to delete. So, I end with only the .pdf, so close enough, with this I think I won't need the build directory.